# Is the error that I am using a cursor or is there an issue with the rest of this script?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-cursor

This code works fine in SQL 2005 but appears to miss a random number of records from the end of the select in SQL 2008 or SQL 2008R2.  I use this code to backup databases on my production servers.  The 2008 Server has 37 db's on it (not counting tempdb) and it backs up between 17 to 35 of those db's each day (even though if I run the select I always get 37 rows returned). The job it is in completes with no errors, but doesn't back up all of the databases.

```
DECLARE @today VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @today = Convert(varchar(10),dateadd(day,0,Dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)),120)

DECLARE @DBName varchar(500)
DECLARE DB_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
OPEN DB_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM DB_Cursor INTO @DBNAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
IF @DBNAME <> 'tempdb'
BEGIN
    declare @Path varchar(500)              
    select @Path = 'g:\DBBackups\'

    declare @FileName varchar(4000)
    select @FileName = @Path + @DBNAME + '_Full_' + @today + '.bak'

        BACKUP DATABASE @DBName 
            TO DISK = @FileName
            WITH NoInit, NoFormat, SKIP
END

  FETCH NEXT FROM DB_Cursor INTO @DBNAME;
END;
CLOSE DB_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE DB_Cursor;
```

Comment: Why are you using a script to do this? Why not use a Database Maintenance Plan instead?

Comment: It was this way when I got here, and I haven't had time to clean it up... now may be a good time.

Comment: Actually just more curious at this point as to why something that I avoid but usually feel I can count on if I absolutely had to is now showing signs that it may not be as reliable as I thought! (cursors)

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be anything jumping out that looks wrong. Maybe there is a time out issue or invalid characters in the db name that the backup statement doesn't like. I would suggest using the DB Maint Plan. Much safer IMHO :)

Comment: I disagree with the maintenance plan suggestion. If you just implement the default it does all kinds of bad things, such as shrinks and blanket index defrag/rebuild stuff. This is just a cursor options issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked about this briefly starting here:

- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Basically, change the cursor to use `READ_ONLY LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC` and you shouldn't be affected by locks or changes to databases (which is the only wild stab guess I have for an actual explanation). This was the only true difference I could find in all the cases where the mysterious database skipping did not occur.

I did not attempt to investigate the values of `@@FETCH_STATUS` - it is possible that as the cursor progresses, this changes to values other than 0 and -1 (I usually check against the latter, not the former). So maybe change `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` to `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1`.

Comment: I will try these suggestions tonight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, don't use a cursor at all. :)

The script is heavily flawed. It doesn't check the state of the database so if you have a database that is not online like a database mirror or log shipping secondary, the process will fail and all databases that come after it won't be backed up. Also, your using the wrong data types

Comment: To be fair to the original script writer, the script did originally check for database state, but it was removed to test if that option was somehow responsible for the missing backups.  And my biggest concern is that the job skips db's but doesn't fail, so failing the job so I know there is an issue immediately is a plus. But the other comments are fair.